# node_modules CSS files not compiling in production Webpacker

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, font-awesome, webpacker

I am working on a Rails application, which I am using the font-awesome free npm package.
I am including the font-awesome assets in `applcation.js` pack:

```js
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all"); // this line
```

Everything works fine in development and in production as well.

Then I added another package `splideJS`, which contains a CSS file in `node_modules`. I have imported the css file in `application.js` pack like fontawesome:

```js
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all");
require("@splidejs/splide/dist/css/splide.min");
```

This works on development but not in production. Why?

My thinking is that webpacker only compiles js files, but not CSS in production. So I tried to make webpacker compile CSS files by using `stylesheet_pack_tag` and created `application.scss` file inside `packs` folder.

```
// packs/application.scss
@import "@splidejs/splide/dist/css/splide.min";

// application.html.haml
= stylesheet_pack_tag "application", media: "all"
```

Now webpacker is compiling splideJS stylesheets, and it is working in production. **BUT** font-awesome stopped working. **Why?**

Another question, What is this line for in `webpacker.yml`? It's set to false only in production, I tried to change it to true, but also it doesn't work.

```
# Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
compile: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but the way I imported Splide on Rails 6 (working on dev and prod) was using the "import" option on application.js and mounting it:

```
import Splide from '@splidejs/splide';
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  // Call your functions here, e.g:
  // initSelect2();
  new Splide( '.splide' ).mount();
});
```

For the CSS, I imported like you did on application.scss:

```
@import "@splidejs/splide/dist/css/splide.min";
```

I hope this may help you.
Best!